# Serializing/deserializing aliased primitives in Jackson without too much boilerplate

Tags: java, json, jackson2

I have a class I want to deserlialize into a Java into a class. One of the class attributes is itself a serializable class which has one primitive (String) parameter and really represents an aliased String, i.e., a String with some extra stuff around it to make sure it comes in the correct format. This is useful in a variety of applications (e.g., identifiers), in this case it's a Cron string that has to have specific representation. So I have

```
class ScheduleConfigurations {
    private Cron cron;
    private Set<Cron> overrides;
    // other attributes, getters/setters, constructor
}


class Cron {
    private String cronString;

    private void validate() { // validates string has correct representation }
    // getters, setters, constructor
}
```

Obviously the standard Jackson deserializer expects a JSON of the format

```
{
    "cron": {
        "cronString": "someCronString",
    "overrides": [
        { "cronString": "someCronString1" },
        { "cronString": "someCronString2" }
    ]
}
```

However, the `Cron` class is clearly just an aliased String. I'd want the above to be serialized/deserialized as

```
{
    "cron": "someCronString",
    "overrides": ["someCronString1", "someCronString2"]
}
```

I can make that happen with a custom serializer with a bunch of boilerplate, but I am looking for an elegant way to say to Jackson "hey, this class has one String attribute, just pass through it and treat its serialized representation as its only attribute".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the entire object to be (de)serialized as a string, it's very easy:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
class Cron {
    private String cronString;
    public Cron(String cronString) { // Called by Jackson when deserializing from JSON string
        this.cronString = cronString;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() { // Called by Jackson when serializing to JSON
        return this.cronString;
    }
}
```

Since the class is just a wrapper around a string, you don't even need getter, setter, or other constructor, not even for other Java code, though you can of course still have them.

*Test*

```
ScheduleConfigurations configObj = new ScheduleConfigurations();
configObj.setCron(new Cron("someCronString"));
configObj.setOverrides(new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(
        new Cron("someCronString1"), new Cron("someCronString2"))));
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(configObj));
```

```
String json = "{\r\n" + 
              "  \"cron\" : \"someCronString\",\r\n" + 
              "  \"overrides\" : [ \"someCronString1\", \"someCronString2\" ]\r\n" + 
              "}";
ScheduleConfigurations configObj = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, ScheduleConfigurations.class);
System.out.println("cron = " + configObj.getCron());
System.out.println("overrides = " + configObj.getOverrides());
```

*Output*

```json
{
  "cron" : "someCronString",
  "overrides" : [ "someCronString1", "someCronString2" ]
}
```

```
cron = someCronString
overrides = [someCronString1, someCronString2]
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input`. Also, I assumed I also need to add `@JsonDeserialize(using= FromStringDeserializer.class)`  to be able to actually deserialize?

Comment: Managed to get it to work with StringDeserializer. I'll mark this with a check for showing me the StringSerializer option in Jackson I didn't know about!

Comment: @NimrodSadeh I executed that code using Jackson 2.9.8, so I know it works. --- No, you don't need `@JsonDeserialize`, because when the deserializer sees a JSON string mapping to an object field, it will automatically call a **constructor taking a single `String` argument**, like shown in the code here.

Comment: Makes sense. I ran with 2.9.9 so my guess is I was doing something wrong as it should not be that different.

Comment: @NimrodSadeh I just ran it again with `jackson-databind` 2.9.9 as only dependency, the `ScheduleConfigurations` class from the question with getters and setters added, and the code from the answer in a `main` method, nothing else. Worked as-is.